# How to stop ongoing dispatch group execution and start new one?

Tags: ios, swift, background, grand-central-dispatch

So I have a paginated API that I have to call every time a user enters a screen. The below code works fine but has one issue if say API calls are in progress and the user backs down and comes again then rather both execution starts simultaneously.
and has to wait for both executions to be completed.
So, What I want is to stop ongoing API calls and start new ones when requested new one
If this setup is wrong in any way please notify me as well what am I doing wrong?

```
func storeAllData(matchID: Int64) {
        GlobalVariable.isFetchingData = true
        dbManager = DbManager.shared
        if let lastScore = dbManager.getLastBallForCurrentMatch(matchID: matchID) {
            self.fetchAllScore(scoreID: lastScore.id ?? 0, matchID: matchID)
        } else {
            self.fetchAllScore(scoreID: 0, matchID: matchID)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllScore(scoreID: Int = 0, matchID: Int64) {
        let id = matchID
        backgroundQueue.async { [self] in
            autoreleasepool {
                fetchPaginatedData(matchID:Int(id), scoreID: scoreID, page: 1)
                dispatchGroup.wait()
                print("All API calls finished")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPaginatedData(matchID: Int,scoreID: Int = 0, page: Int) {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        MatchesNetworkManager.sharedInstance.getAllScore(matchID: Int64(matchID), scoreID: Int64(scoreID), page: Int64(page), completionHandler: { [weak self] (allSocre, isSuccess, errorStr) in
            
            if isSuccess {
                if allSocre?.match?.scores != nil {
                    self?.oldScores.append(contentsOf: ((allSocre?.match?.scores)!))
                    self?.backgroundQueue.async {
                        if let scores = allSocre?.match?.scores as? [Scores] {
                            self?.dbManager.insertRecords(matchID: matchID, records: scores)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self?.oldScores = []
                                if allSocre?.page_num ?? 0 == 1 {
                                    self?.updateScoreView()
                                }
                                if (allSocre?.page_num ?? 0) < (allSocre?.total_pages ?? 0) {
                                    self?.fetchPaginatedData(matchID: matchID,page: (allSocre?.page_num ?? 1) + 1)
                                } else {
                                    // All pages have been fetched
                                    GlobalVariable.isFetchingData = false
                                    print("All API calls finished")
                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .refreshMarketView, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                                    self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    self?.updateScoreView()
                    GlobalVariable.isFetchingData = false
                }
                
            } else {
                print("API call error: \(errorStr)")
                self?.updateScoreView()
                GlobalVariable.isFetchingData = false
                self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You should use something more modernier then DispatchQueue. Concurrency for example.

Comment: @Cy-4AH
can you provide an example because i have tried dispatchworkitem and blockoperation these are not working

Answer (score 0):

The reality of most concurrency abstractions on these (and similar) platforms is that, once started, work units are almost completely unable to be forcibly cancelled (other than by terminating the process.)

The way one would generally handle this would be to check a flag from *within* the work units themselves that indicates that they should be canceled, at which point they can do whatever cleanup is needed (if any), and return early. If you had a dispatch group, you could associate a flag with the group, and then explicitly check the flag at the beginning of each operation (or at the top of each iteration of a loop within the operation), and returning early if the group is cancelled.

You can do this ad hoc. You can use an existing abstraction (like [`NSOperation`'s `cancel` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation/1411672-cancel)) but even there, you'll note that the first line of the *Discussion* section says: "This method does not force your operation code to stop." Your operation's code must still check the flag.

For example, you could use `NSBlockOperation`, create the operation instance, then capture a zeroing, weak reference to the `NSBlockOperation` instance inside the closure of the block that does the real work, and then use that reference to check whether the `NSBlockOperation` has been canceled (or deallocated).

Long story short, there's no proverbial free lunch here.

Comment: This happened with NSBlockOperation as well ongoing operations didn't stop just new operations executed with old ones and If I add a flag it will terminate my new operation than the old one.

Comment: My point is that there doesn't seem to be a built-in mechanism that does exactly what you want, so you're going to need to create something yourself. If you want to cancel all the old operations, and not the new ones, you'll either need to use multiple separate groups (or opQueues), multiple separate flags, or you'll have to come up with some other data structure on the side that lets you achieve what you want. From your description and comment, it doesn't seem like what you want is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you appear to be looking for cancelable asynchronous tasks. This will be very difficult with your implementation (dispatch groups, using `wait` to block a thread until the request is done). I guess you could theoretically be done by saving the `URLSessionTask` object(s) for the `URLSession` requests (that I presume are buried in your “network manager”) and `cancel` those when the view in question disappears. But that is inelegant.

Back in the day, the advice would be to wrap your asynchronous tasks in an `Operation` subclass, assiduously avoid using dispatch groups, do the appropriate `isFinished`, `isExecuting` KVO notifications. Your `Operation` subclass would override `cancel` to cancel the network request. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560463/1271826 for an example. Anyway, if you implement this sort of `Operation` subclass to wrap your asynchronous work, then canceling the work is fairly simple.

But having suggested how you might do it with legacy API (namely, operation queues), I must confess that I would not consider that for a second, nowadays. Instead, we would reach for Swift concurrency. That not only manages dependencies for asynchronous tasks, but the standard `URLSession` methods [`data(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767353-data) and [`data(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data) natively support cancelation. (This is assuming you are even using `URLSession`; you have not shared the relevant code with us.) You will end up with code that is simpler, handles asynchronous dependencies, and supports cancelation. But it will require a more thorough rewrite of code that you have not shared, so we cannot even start to advise you on specifics. But see WWDC videos [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132) and [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) (and other videos linked in the respective “related videos” sections therein).

---

In the comments below, you noted that you are using Alamofire. It uses `URLSession` and supports Swift concurrency.

E.g., consider this sort of legacy approach with Alamofire:

```swift
class LegacyNetworkManager {
    static let shared = LegacyNetworkManager()

    private init() { }

    func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[Post], AFError>) -> Void) {
        AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .response(responseSerializer: .decodable(of: [Post].self)) { response in
                completion(response.result)
            }
    }
}
```

You could, instead, adopt Swift concurrency with Alamofire, and you now have a cancelable API:

```swift
actor NetworkManager {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()

    private init() { }

    func posts() async throws -> [Post] {
        try await AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .serializingDecodable([Post].self)
            .value
    }
}
```

With this cancelable rendition, you can then do things like:

```swift
import os.log

private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "SwiftConcurrencyViewController")

class SwiftConcurrencyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private let networkManager = NetworkManager.shared
    private let databaseManager = DatabaseManager.shared

    private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

    var posts: [Post] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PostCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
    }
    
    // start request when view appears …

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        logger.debug("launching task")
        task = Task { await fetch() }
    }

    // … but if not finished by the time the view disappears, cancel it

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        logger.debug("canceling (if not already done)")
        task?.cancel()
    }
}

extension SwiftConcurrencyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    …
}

private extension SwiftConcurrencyViewController {
    func fetch() async {
        do {
            logger.debug("fetching")
            posts = try await networkManager.posts()
            logger.debug("fetched")
            tableView.reloadData()
            try await databaseManager.save(posts)
        } catch {
            logger.error("\(error)")
            show(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/robertmryan/AlamofireWithSwiftConcurrency for [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) contrasting GCD and Swift concurrency approaches.

Now, I recognize that this is dramatically different from your example (because you did not share enough of your implementation), so don’t get too lost in the weeds of my example, but note that:

- Even in the GCD example, we would not use dispatch groups; but
- By adopting Swift concurrency, we can not only manage dependencies between asynchronous tasks, but also enjoying cancelation logic.

Comment: I am not using URLSession i am using alamofire to call api.
so if i switch to urlsession i can stop ongoing task and start new ?
and this will happen on background ?
I have not tried concurrency yet this is first time and i am confused.

Comment: can you guide how can i achieve required need?

Comment: Well Alamofire is based on `URLSession` and [it supports Swift Concurrency](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-swift-concurrency), so you’re in luck. So, try that out.

Comment: Once you’ve got that tackled, you can then marry that with your storage API (probably put that in its own actor, to get it off the main thread). Then, when you’ve done that, you can then tackle the cancelation handling (e.g., if SwiftUI, you’d use `.task` view modifier, which is canceled for you automatically; if UIKit, you’d wrap the call to your new `async` function in a `Task` object, which you can save and `cancel` when needed). You haven’t supplied enough details to us to do this all for you, and it’s too many separate issues for a single question. So tackle it one step at a time.